# Is it possible to take C++ libraries from a future Android release (2.3.3) and use them on a previous release (2.1)?

Tags: java, android, c++

More specifics: I specifically need the BitmapRegionDecoder that was introduced in 2.3.3, but our company is currently designing for Andriod 2.1. Would it be possible, using the NDK, or some other method to package [BitmapRegionDecoder.cpp](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.cpp), which is what the Java class is all about, and the minimal amount of dependencies to use with my 2.1 application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. That's the point of making people upgrade:-)

Comment: Without being expert in native applications, but why not? You have the source code, compile it and it by using NDK. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is a convention about version numbers of the form **x.y.z**. However, I am not sure, if this applies to Your problem:

If **x** changes, then You can neither upgrade nor downgrade. An application that needs a library in version 2.y.z cannot use the library in version 1.... oder version 3....

If only **y** changes, then You can only upgrade. An application that needs a library in version 2.3.z will run with version 2.4... but is not guaranteed to work with version 2.2...

If only **z** changes, then You can upgrade and downgrade. An application that needs a library in version 2.3.3 will run with 2.3.2 and 2.3.4.

Changes in x indicate a major redesign of a library. Changes in y indicate new functionality of a library without modifying the existing one. Changes in z are mostly bugfixes.